# How to listen to "ref" object changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Consider following example. I have a *ref* of a div and I want to pass this *ref* to *Child*. **BUT** if I just use it as it is right now, the *Child* is not re-rendered when the *ref* object updates and stores the proper *HTML* element.

I can make a fix for it and use the *callback* approach with `useCallback`. Just uncomment the commented line and see that then it works properly (both solutions) because *parent* re-renders due to state update so the correct *ref* is passed also from the first approach.

**QUESTION**: Is there a way to AVOID using state and somehow let *Child* know that *ref* object updated in the parent?

**Note**: I know I can use `useEffect` in *Child* and listen to the `someRef` changes but I want to have access to the *someRef* object in the function body, not only within the hook body.

```js
const { useState, useRef, useCallback } = React;

const Child = ({ someRef, node }) => {
  console.log(someRef, node); // someRef is always null and doesnt update...

  return null;
}

const App = () => {
  /* 1st approach */
  const someRef = useRef(null);
  
  /* 2nd approach */
  const [node, setNode] = useState(null);
  
  const someRef2 = useCallback(n => {
    if (n !== null) {
        // setNode(n)   <----- uncomment to see it works
    }
  }, []);
  
  return (
     <div>
      <div ref={someRef}>text1</div>
      <div ref={someRef2}>text2</div>
      <Child someRef={someRef} node={node} />
     </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: have child check a global variable.. if this globalVar==1, globalVar=0; doWhatever

Comment: This looks like a [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to be honest. Could you describe your overall goal? The reference value will become available **after** rendering, so `useEffect(() => { console.log(someRef) }, [someRef])` would do the trick. However this just seems wrong. If you can describe your overall problem better you might find a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

No, as far as I know, there is no way to subscribe / be notified on `ref` changes.

From [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) on `useRef`:

> Keep in mind that `useRef` **doesn’t notify you when its content changes.** Mutating the `.current` property **doesn’t cause a re-render.** If you want to run some code when React attaches or detaches a ref to a DOM node, you may want to use a callback ref instead.

At the end of the day, your app will have to respond to changes in state. Either the parent's or own child state.

You even might update the `ref` during the render phase of the parent so it will be kept "in sync" with any `state` changes on the parent. But after all what will trigger updates is the `state` change, and not the ref's.

Comment: "you may want to use a callback ref instead." what does it mean?

Comment: Here is the docs on [callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs). Personally, I've never used it. But from the example they show on the docs, it seems that the same behavior might be easily achieved using `useRef + useEffect` instead of the `callback ref` pattern. With `useEffect`, it would be really easy to _"run some code when React attaches or detaches a ref to a DOM node"_ as they mention in the docs.

Comment: Basically, when the `useEffect` runs. The `ref` to the DOM node already exists. No there's no need to use a `ref` callback in that case. The example on the docs seems like an outdated pattern. Should sill work, though.